# Pushing same TableViewController into navigation stack multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

for my app i need to push same TableViewController more then once. When user taps in didSelect, i need to push same controller in navigation stack.

My app is file manager app and it connects to ftp server and shows user what is inside. But there might be folders inside folders that contains more folders(infinite).

For this i can't create lots of TableViewControllers in storyboard and when i try to push same controller into navigation stack with this:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(self, animated: true)
```

I get error says that i can't push same controller in nav stack.
So i create new instance of my controller and try to push like this:

`let newMyTableVC = MyTableVC()
 navigationController?.pushViewController(newMyTableVC, animated: true)`

But with this i also get error says that:

> 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier FolderCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

So what i understand from this error that my first TableViewController uses my cells identifier and it's on memory. When i try to pass new instance of my TableViewController with same cell identifier, it crashes because cell already exists with same identifier.(I might be so wrong).

```
If i am on right track doing this with approach at the above {
    How do i reuse cells with dynamic identifier and provide data to them.
} else {
    How do i accomplish what i want?
  }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why create a new controller each time and not just change the dataset to match that of the current directory? Then use the TableView's reloadData() functionality?

Comment: Its a perfectly good approach.  Give the table view controller a storyboard id, and instantiate with self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithId.

Comment: hey guys thanks for replying. I need to create new controller each time because i want user to be able to get back from last folder view controller in cache without waiting for new network request and reloading of tableView. Also it is bad user experience when user taps cell and you reload data instead of pushing new view controller into navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new instance like this:

```
let newMyTableVC = MyTableVC()
```

it is quite independent of the storyboard.  Importantly, it therefore knows nothing about the prototype cells defined in the storyboard.  Hence the relevant bit of the error is "...or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard".

To avoid this problem, set an identifier for your table view controller in the storyboard, and then use:

```
let newMyTableVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier") as! MyTableVC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works perfectly. I've never thought this way even i have used this method many times. So is this the approach i should use whenever i need instance of view controller in storyboard?

Comment: @YasinNazlıcan Yes, if you want to use design and layout from the storyboard you must either use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier OR use a segue.